# Edit Action Form To Controller

Tags: java, spring, forms, model-view-controller

I cannot get the data on my edit form upon submission

Here's my jsp/form
I have an attribute but my data is a List coming from this "${SPRING_FALL_PLAN_NUMBER_LIST}"

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="EditSpringFallPlanNumberActionForm" 
             modelAttribute="EditSpringFallPlanNumberFormAttribute"  role="form">    

    <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 align="left" style="width: 25%">    
       <tr>  
          <td class="responsive" align="center"><b>UID</b></td>
          <td class="responsive" align="center"><b>Fall Plan Number</b></td>
          <td class="responsive" align="center"><b>Spring Plan Number</b></td>
       </tr>        
       <c:forEach var="springFallPlanNumberValue" items="${SPRING_FALL_PLAN_NUMBER_LIST}">            
        <tr>
            <td class="responsive" align="center">
               <input type="text"  value="${springFallPlanNumberValue.UID}" style="text-align:center;"/> 
            </td>
            <td class="responsive" align="center">
               <input type="text" value="${springFallPlanNumberValue.fallPlanNumber}" style="text-align:center;"/> 
            </td>
            <td class="responsive" align="center">
              <input type="text"  value="${springFallPlanNumberValue.springPlanNumber}" style="text-align:center;"/>  
            </td>
         </tr>
       </c:forEach> ....
```

.............
....

And here's my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/EditSpringFallPlanNumberActionForm" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "saveUpdateSpringFallPlanNumber" })
public ModelAndView saveUpdateSpringFallPlanNumberConfigValues(
        @ModelAttribute("EditSpringFallPlanNumberFormAttribute")  ArrayList<FallSpringPlanNumber> fallSpringPlanNumber,
        HttpSession session, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        Model model){......
```

.......

I"m expecting the parameter "ArrayList fallSpringPlanNumber" to have values and its coming from update form but it's empty on submit

Comment: does on submit form hit your controller ?

Comment: You have declared `saveUpdateSpringFallPlanNumber` as param in controller but in html you haven't mention it.